# Not able to read Bluetooth Characteristic in android app

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

I am trying to read a bluetooth characteristic (CPU temperature of Raspberry pi, [cputemp](https://github.com/Douglas6/cputemp)). But when I my checking the permission using `it.properties` it's returning `18` and `discoveredGatt.readCharacteristic` is not getting called. I also tried running without using `if (it.properties == BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ)` but in both the cases, `onCharacteristicChanged` and `onCharacteristicRead` are not getting called.

Edit:

```
private class GattClientCallback:BluetoothGattCallback(){

        override fun onConnectionStateChange(gatt: BluetoothGatt?, status: Int, newState: Int) {
            super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState)
            val isSuccess = status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS
            val isConnected = newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED


            if(isSuccess && isConnected){
                gatt?.discoverServices()
                Log.d(TAG,"Connection state changed: $isSuccess $isConnected")
            }
        }

        override fun onServicesDiscovered(discoveredGatt: BluetoothGatt?, status: Int) {
            super.onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status)
            if(status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS){
                gatt = discoveredGatt
                Log.d(TAG,"Services discovered")
                val service = discoveredGatt?.getService(UUID.fromString("00000001-710e-4a5b-8d75-3e5b444bc3cf"))
                if(service!=null){
                    Log.d(TAG,"Service found")
                    service.characteristics.forEach {

                        Log.d(TAG,"Characteristic: ${it.uuid}")
                        Log.d(TAG,"Characteristic permission: ${it.permissions}")
                        Log.d(TAG,"Characteristic properties: ${it.properties}")

                        if (it.properties == BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ){
                            Log.d(TAG,"Characteristic is readable")
                            discoveredGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(it,true)
                            discoveredGatt.readCharacteristic(it)
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        override fun onCharacteristicChanged(
            gatt: BluetoothGatt,
            characteristic: BluetoothGattCharacteristic,
            value: ByteArray
        ) {
            super.onCharacteristicChanged(gatt, characteristic, value)
            Log.d(TAG,"Characteristic changed: ${characteristic.uuid}")
            Log.d(TAG,"Characteristic value: ${value.toString(Charsets.UTF_8)}")
            
        }

        override fun onCharacteristicRead(
            gatt: BluetoothGatt,
            characteristic: BluetoothGattCharacteristic,
            value: ByteArray,
            status: Int
        ) {
            super.onCharacteristicRead(gatt, characteristic, value, status)
            Log.d(TAG,"Characteristic read: ${characteristic.uuid}")
            Log.d(TAG,"Characteristic value: ${value.toString(Charsets.UTF_8)}")
        }
    }
```

Tried checking for property on the gatt server, characteristic has both read and notify permissions.

Edit:
I am able to read the characteristic using nRF Connect app:
[nRF Connect screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xgHs.jpg)

Here is the output:[Run output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZVz4.png)

Comment: Have you tried reading the characteristic using a generic BLE tool such as [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile)?

Comment: Do you see the `Log.d(TAG,"Characteristic is readable")` in the logcat when you test it? Note that the `setCharacteristicNotification` should return true so that you get the `onCharacteristicChanged` notification. HOWEVER you better add all relevant `BluetoothGattCallback` implementation so that we can see if something is missing in your implementation.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry for late response, I have added the code for the BluetoothGattCallback implementation and also added screenshot of the output and  nRF connect app reading the value of characteristic.